# Want to parse an xml file and write into a CSV file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, csv

I'm new to using python (just learning). My task that I'm trying to complete using python is: To parse thru many xml files in 1 folder - the structure is the same for each xml file. I would like to write all of this data to 1 large csv file. The header of the CSV file would be the attributes of the xml files.

Here is a sample of 1 of the xml files:

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <XACTDOC>
    <XACTNET_INFO
      transactionId = "0254XLM"
      origTransactionId = "0254XLM"
      carrierExternalUniqueId = "6533277"
      carrierId = "2570210"
      carrierName = "Company_Name"
      contractorName = "ContractorSoenSo"
      recipientsXNAddress = "text"
      recipientsName = "moreText"
    >
      <CONTROL_POINTS>
        <CONTROL_POINT
          stamp = "2014-10-20T16:02:08"
          createdStamp = "2014-10-20T16:02:08"
          type = "Notification Pending"
          status = "2"
        />
      </CONTROL_POINTS>
    </XACTNET_INFO>
    <CONTACTS/>
    <ADM>
      <COVERAGE_LOSS
        claimNumber = "123456-78"
      />
    </ADM>
  </XACTDOC>
```

Any help you could offer would be great!

Comment: Check out the Element Tree XML API for Python as well as Python's read/write to CSV capabilities. These are both available on the Python libraries at docs.python.org/

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are just looking to get started have a look at the python documents for the XML and CSV libraries also this tutorial might be relevant: http://www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html

Comment: I have gone thru a bunch of the ElementTree demo's and exercises. I am able to parse my own xml file, and navigate thru the root/child elements & print them on my screen. I didn't look into the creating an xml file using python, well because I don't have to yet. I don't know how to get from being able to navigate thru the parsed xml to showing the xml file as a csv file. What am I missing? Also I tried loading lxml library but I don't have administrator rights on my work laptop :(